# Google drive appears empty only in Chrome in Android Emulator

Tags: android, reactjs, google-chrome, webview, google-drive-api

I have a react javascript app that uses Google OAuth to gain user consent and get read access to the user's google drive. It works fine in all browsers on a laptop - users can open the google drive file picker and see all files. However, when I access the same app using Chrome running in an Android Studio emulator, the google drive file picker opens but it is empty. On the same Android emulator, I installed Firefox and the file picker shows the expected list of files.

I am trying this on an emulator because one of my users is reporting a similar issue on a android based interactive flat panel, and I don't have the hardware to replicate the same problem locally.

The user agent string had an issue initially which was causing the file picker to not even open up. After fixing the user agent string, the picker now opens up on all devices but only Chrome on Android Emulator has this file listing issue.

I have also checked that all cookies are allowed in the Chrome settings. Any tips on what else I could check ?